# systemd-networkd-wait-online.service won't finish successfully even after drop-in patch

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, systemd-networkd

I've noticed that `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` is always down on my laptop. Using the advice on this [Arch Linux Wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd-networkd#systemd-networkd-wait-online), I edited the service file: `systemctl edit systemd-networkd-wait-online`, and added the following to the file `/etc/systemd/system/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service.d/override.conf`:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online --any
```

After reloading the daemons (`systemctl daemon-reload`), I restarted the service: `systemctl restart systemd-networkd-wait-online`. However, after two minutes, the service still failed. What can I do?

---

I have working network interfaces; here's the output of `ip a`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b4:45:06:50:6b:7a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a8:93:4a:ac:d7:73 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.20.10.9/28 brd 172.20.10.15 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp3s0
       valid_lft 81362sec preferred_lft 81362sec
    inet6 fe80::3902:41a4:241f:a7ad/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:52:af:c1:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Thinking that this might be because I'm using my phone's hotspot, I've also tried it with a working ethernet connection, but still failed:

```
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b4:45:06:50:6b:7a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.42/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute enp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a540:801:603d:d8e9/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Output of `systemctl status systemd-networkd-wait-online`:

```
× systemd-networkd-wait-online.service - Wait for Network to be Configured
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2023-10-19 11:43:19 BST; 15min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-networkd-wait-online.service(8)
    Process: 3401 ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online --any (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 3401 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 8ms

Oct 19 11:41:19 main systemd[1]: Starting Wait for Network to be Configured...
Oct 19 11:43:19 main systemd-networkd-wait-online[3401]: Timeout occurred while waiting for network connectivity.
Oct 19 11:43:19 main systemd[1]: systemd-networkd-wait-online.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 19 11:43:19 main systemd[1]: systemd-networkd-wait-online.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 19 11:43:19 main systemd[1]: Failed to start Wait for Network to be Configured.
```

I'm not providing the output of `journalctl -xeu systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` since it's already replicated by `systemctl status`.

`networkctl` output:

```
IDX LINK        TYPE     OPERATIONAL SETUP    
  1 lo          loopback carrier     unmanaged
  2 enp2s0      ether    no-carrier  unmanaged
  3 wlp3s0      wlan     routable    unmanaged
  4 docker0     bridge   routable    unmanaged
  8 vethc59fd34 ether    enslaved    unmanaged

5 links listed.
```

Comment: What's the output of `networkctl`?

Comment: @TomYan I've added it as an edit to the question.

Comment: I'm not so sure if wait-online consider unmanaged interfaces.